# How to define half full multidimentional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

It may be too stupid question but I cant figure it out. using this atm

```
  private static String[][][] ns=new String[][][]{{{"52","14",""},{"90","34",""},{"","",""}},{{"89","",""},{"67","78",""},{"","",""}},...
```

rest of the elements are {"","",""}.. so array ns must be ns[10][3][3]. How can I define this instead of writing all {"","",""}...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't init your array via `new T[] {}`.

```
String[][][] ns = new String[10][3][3];
for (int i = 0; i < ns.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ns[i].length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < ns[i][j].length; k++) {
            ns[i][j][k] = "";
        }
    }
}

ns[0][0][0] = "52";
ns[0][0][1] = "14";

ns[0][1][0] = "90";
ns[0][1][1] = "34";

ns[0][3][0] = "89";

ns[0][4][0] = "67";
ns[0][4][1] = "78";
```